Which is better approach SSIS SOURCE XML Component or SQL OPENXML?
I need to know which is better approach to down load nested XML into tables. Is SSIS package inbuilt XML SOURCE or OPENXML?
I have tried n=both the ways, SSIS component takes long time to downlaod date into tables where is OPENXML is vey quick.

Microsoft proprietary OPENXML() and its companions sp_xml_preparedocument and sp_xml_removedocument are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL
Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.
Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is strongly recommended to re-write your SQL and switch it to XQuery.
Also, OPENXML() cannot take advantage of XML indexes while XQuery methods can.

There are lots of ways to solve this issue.  My preference is to use Powershell.  I parse xml using the Net library Xml Linq and any database commands I use the PS cmdlet Invoke-sqlcmd.  Better can mean lots of things.  Why are you asking better when OpenXml runs much faster than SSIS.

Thank you. I would consider XQUERYgoing forward.

Thank you. I would consider XQuery going forward. At this moment I have to develop ETL in SSIS package to populate tables from XML and for this I am using inbuilt SSIS component called "XML SOURCE". My question is whether I should use component XML SOURCE or populate tables through XQuery. Please help.
